# Windows angular need to create files with CRLF endings

Tags: angular, windows, visual-studio-code, atom-editor, line-endings

I'm on windows and want in my angular project the cli to create components with CRLF endings.
Right now angular CLI creates scss file with CRLF and other files (ts, html and test) with LF.
In my global settings I've set  `git config --global core.autocrlf true` command, but unfortunately it doesn't work.
Also tried to create components from atom and visual studio code editors and still, no results.

Maybe you can give me some hints.